# Django error message not showing for invalid login

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-authentication, django-3.0

I have used `auth` to perform login functionality in Django. However, whenever I enter an invalid password it does not show an error message.

**login.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Log in</h2>
  <form method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% if field.errors %}
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif%}
      </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Log in</button>

  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('ecomm.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Please post your views and forms code also.

Comment: Have you had a look at my explanation? Do ask if you have any doubts

Answer (score 0):

> The most common cause of this error is when you create a new `form`,
> replacing the form which contains the `form.errors` and returning it
> to the template.

If you are using the django.contrib.auth.views.login then the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) says that you should specify the `action` in the form and assign it to

`{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}`.

You should change your `form` to

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
```

**If this doesn't solve your problem, please consider adding your relevant `views.py` code to your question.**